# how to avoid selection of duplicate html row to clone using jquery

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass, jquery-append

After a click on a 'td' of table 1, i append some cells from that row to another table (table 2) without moving/changing that row from table 1.

Now to avoid duplication i added class to that 'td' from table 1.
Like this

```
$(".table1 td:first-child + td").click(function(){

  $("#table2").append('<tr><td>clicked TD value from table 1</td>  more td's</tr>');  
  $(this).addClass('done'); 
}):
```

Now when i tried to remove that appended row from table2...i have to remove the class 'done'
which is i added to cliked 'td' of table1.

How to do this?? is there any other way of doing this (avoiding duplication) other than adding class??

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h6zYJ/1/).

pls help.
thanks

Comment: Can you please bring more info ? A [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) might be useful to see what you are exactly trying to do and get all constraints involved `;)`

Comment: instead you have to pass something unique to both row like done1, so while remove table2 row you can get it correspond row of table1

Comment: @f00bar, just added fiddle in the post.

Comment: When i click on the 'name' field ..nothing gets appended thats the first problem.. and when removing that row from 2nd table how to remove the class which i added???

Comment: So basically you want to duplicate rows from table selection into #destiny table when clicking any name from table selection, but not if the name you clicked has it's row already copied into the #destiny table right ?

Comment: yeah, exactly.. f00bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a deep revision of your code

Fiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/stphane/KPe9T/)

```
$(function () {
    $("#selections tbody").on('click', function (e) {
        var $td = $(e.target);
        if ($td.prevAll('td').length === 1) {
                var $destiny = $('#destiny'),
                                // Any row in destiny that would be a clone of the current clicked td's row
            // You may want to put an id to make sure it is uniq
                $trDestiny = $('tr[rel="' + $td.text() + '"]', $destiny);
                // ...
            if (!$trDestiny.length) {
                // Insert new row ...
            }
            // else {error handling here}
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KPe9T/6/ i updated the fiddle, i couldn't understand some of the code ...will you elaborate .???

Comment: Sure, I can ! Now check [8th revision](http://jsfiddle.net/KPe9T/8/)... By the way, please set the answer as the solution to consider my work `;)`